# How to do this query with Eloquent / Laravel: subquery WHERE IN with GROUP BY

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying with no success make this (in MySQL):

```
SELECT * FROM tableName
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT MAX(id)
    FROM tableName
    GROUP BY var1, var2, var3
);
```

into an **Eloquent** query.  This isn't working:

```
    $output = TableName::whereIn('id', function($query){
                $query->select(\DB::raw(
                           'SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE id IN (
                            SELECT MAX(id)
                            FROM TableName
                            GROUP BY var1, var1, var1);'))
                })->get(); dd($output);
```

I expect to get the same output than in MySQL (Workbench).
Please Help! thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your output on MySQL(Workbench) then? Maybe showing us that will help us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@techienomics you  may try this;

```php
$output = TableName::select('*')
           ->whereRaw('id1 in (SELECT MAX(id2) FROM tableName group by var1,var2,var3)')
           ->get();
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: thanks Andrew's! It's working for me. Thanks again!

Comment: You are most welcome. Please do well to mark that as the ***solution*** to help others.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$output = TableName::whereIn('id', function($query){
            $query->select(\DB::raw(
                       'SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE id IN (
                        SELECT MAX(id)
                        FROM TableName
                        GROUP BY var1, var1, var1);'))
            });

dd($output->toSql(), $output->getBindings());
```

you will have pure sql and its values

Comment: thanks Mateus, I can't do this code work for me. Andrew's proposal works as expected:

$output = TableName::select('*')
           ->whereRaw('id1 in (SELECT MAX(id2) FROM tableName group by var1,var2,var3)')
           ->get();

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this one

```
$output = TableName::whereIn('id', function($query){
            $query->select(\DB::raw('SELECT MAX(id) FROM TableName'))
                  ->groupBy(['var1', 'var1', 'var1'])
            })->get();
```

I don't know if var1 var1 is the same. If its the same then maybe you can just go with `->groupBy('var1')`

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks Jovs, there are ' ' missing into $query->select I guess. Andrew's proposal works as expected:

$output = TableName::select('*')
           ->whereRaw('id1 in (SELECT MAX(id2) FROM tableName group by var1,var2,var3)')
           ->get();

Thanks again!